# heterogeneous bulk update in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I know that we can bulk update documents in mongodb with

```
db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )
```

in one db call, but it's homogeneous, i.e. all those documents impacted are following one kind of criteria. But what I'd like to do is something like

```
db.collection.update([{criteria1, objNew1}, {criteria2, objNew2}, ...]
```

, to send multiple update request which would update maybe absolutely different documents or class of documents in single db call.

What I want to do in my app is to insert/update a bunch of objects with compound primary key, if the key is already existing, update it; insert it otherwise.

Can I do all these in one combine in mongodb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's two seperate questions. To the first one; there is no MongoDB native mechanism to bulk send criteria/update pairs although technically doing that in a loop yourself is bound to be about as efficient as any native bulk support.

Checking for the existence of a document based on an embedded document (what you refer to as compound key, but in the interest of correct terminology to avoid confusion it's better to use the mongo name in this case) and insert/update depending on that existence check can be done with upsert :

document A :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    key: {
        name: "Will",
        age: 20
    }
}

db.users.update({name:"Will", age:20}, {$set:{age: 21}}), true, false)
```

This upsert (update with insert if no document matches the criteria) will do one of two things depending on the existence of document A :

- Exists : Performs update "$set:{age:21}" on the existing document
- Doesn't exist : Create a new document with fields "name" and field
  "age" with values "Will" and "20" respectively (basically the
  criteria are copied into the new doc) and then the update is applied
  ($set:{age:21}). End result is a document with "name"="Will" and
  "age"=21.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. To the first point, won't it be much more efficient to send multiple criteria/update pairs in one db call especially when there're tons of documents to update and mongodb driver/server reside in different machines? The second question you mentioned is not a new question. Maybe i didn't present it well. What i mean _the compound key_ is nothing to do with _id, it's just two fields (say, type and name) of the document, and i use them united to determine whether the object already exists in db, and the op to use. It's just for scenario representing purpose.

Comment: Hi. Yes that would be more efficient but such a bulk operation is currently only supported for inserts. One of the reasons might be that it's tricky to present possible errors back to the client per update attempt. Report it as an issue/question at jira.mongodb.com if you feel this should be added. I did misunderstand the second part of your question due to terminology. What you need sounds like a basic upsert. I'll edit my answer accordingly so check if that helps you.

Comment: Yes, `getLastError` maybe an issue if bulk update with multiple criteria is support, and things could be more complicated if transaction is adopted. So I've changed my implementation with update loop, and upsert exactly fit into it now. Resolved!

Answer (score 1):

we are seeing some benefits of $in clause. 
our use case was to update the 'status' in a document for a large number number records. 
In our first cut, we were doing a for loop and doing updates one by 1. But then we switched to using $in clause and that made a huge improvement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real benefit from doing updates the way you suggest.

The reason that there is a bulk insert API and that it is faster is that Mongo can write all the new documents sequentially to memory, and update indexes and other bookkeeping in one operation.

A similar thing happens with updates that affect more than one document: the update will traverse the index only once and update objects as they are found.

Sending multiple criteria with multiple criteria cannot benefit from any of these optimizations. Each criteria means a separate query, just as if you issued each update separately. The only possible benefit would be sending slightly fewer bytes over the connection. The database would still have to do each query separately and update each document separately.

All that would happen would be that Mongo would queue the updates internally and execute them sequentially (because only one update can happen at any one time), this is exactly the same as if all the updates were sent separately.

It's unlikely that the overhead in sending the queries separately would be significant, Mongo's global write lock will be the limiting factor anyway.

Comment: I think you forgot: bulk insert reduces the number of server roundtrips. Bulk update would do the same.

Comment: That can be a factor in some cases, but for the general case the added roundtrips are not an issue because of the global write lock. For many other databases you are entirely correct, and in the future it may be true for Mongo too.